# Angular mask - string manipulation

Tags: angular, input, mask

I need to have the input field with possibility to pass **only lowercase letters and digits**. I could use custom mask like this:

```
customPattern = { 'a': { pattern: new RegExp('[a-z0-9]')}};
```

This mask doesn't allow insert uppercase letters. This is what I need...but...

I also need to be able to type letters for example with accidentally active capslock. 
When I type **'A'** it has to be displayed **'a'** in the input field.

---

update:

I need to change value of input field, not only dislplay format of that value...I am passing this value from component to validator by **validate(control: AbstractControl)** method for further validation... So I need to change value of control.

Comment: Use replace instead

Comment: You can use `.toLowerCase()` before checking. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/toLowerCase

Comment: use lowercase pipe: https://angular.io/api/common/LowerCasePipe

Answer (score 0):

You make use of value attribute of the input like below.

```
 <input name="name" [value]="name.toLowerCase()" [(ngModel)]="name" (change)="update()">

update() {
      if (this.name) {
          this.name = this.name.toLowerCase();
      }
    }
```

demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-forms-rfa37f

Comment: I need to change value of input field, not only dislplay format of that value...I am passing this value from component to validator by **validate(control: AbstractControl)** method for further validation... So I need to change value of **control**.

Comment: Okay, for that you may add change event and update the model to the lowercase. you can check the updated answer.

Comment: Other way could be, before passing to validate , update the control value with lower case.

Comment: One more way could be , just allow regex for Capitals(A-Z) as well. So that validate will not fail. and when you are sending data to backend , just update control value to lowercase.